# VB.net syntax for HTML.Hiddenfor to pass string value

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I've been searching for about a century on what must be a simple answer.  I'm trying to pass a string via a hidden field using the HTML.HiddenFor.  Below you can see my code, and the Username and Password parameters pass successfully but I can't get the logAction property to pass in the same way.

Note:  I'm using vb.net, I have a feeling most of the stuff I'm seeing online is for C#.

```
<partial name="_login" />

@ModelType KBLV2.User

@Using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
@<fieldset>
    <legend>Login</legend>

    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(True)


    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.Username)</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(Function(model) model.Username)</td>
            <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.Username)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.Password)</td>
            <td>@Html.PasswordFor(Function(model) model.Password)</td>
            <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.Password)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.HiddenFor(Function(model) model.logAction, New{value = "ON"})</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Login" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</fieldset>
```

End Using

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Man you must be old... "I've been searching for about a century"... And yet you chose VB.NET!?! But still... it's unclear what you're asking...

Comment: :)  I'm new to MVC and I know VB, so figured it would be easier to only learn one language at a time!  What I'm looking for is the correct syntax for the hiddenfor html helper, to pass the string "ON" as the value back to the model along with the username and password.  The username and password fields work as above, but the hiddenfor logAction property isn't taking the "ON" string.

Comment: Never set the `value` attribute when using the `HtmlHelper` methods. You set the value of your `logAction` property to "ON" in the GET method before you pass the model to the view (and then its simply `@Html.HiddenFor(Function(model) model.logAction)`

Comment: Thanks, this helped.  If you want to post as answer I'll mark it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the value from controller side in GET method before return view containing viewmodel class instance:

```
' HomeController
Function Login() As ActionResult
    Dim userVM As New User()
    userVM.logAction = "ON"

    Return View(userVM)
End Function
```

Then, `HiddenFor` helper should be used like this:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(Function(model) model.logAction)
```